# How to get the date for a specific time zone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I need to get the date for a time zone with javascript but *Date* instances get the date of the time zone in which the user is located.

This is the code I used:

```
const date = new Date();
let year = date.getFullYear();
let month = date.getMonth();
let day = date.getDate();
```

Note: I need an answer without the use of jquery.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you want an *actual* (i.e. unformatted) date or if the formatted string (as in the given answer) will suffice. Please cvlarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a time zone when using [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), or [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

For example:

```js
const now = new Date();
const s = now.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
console.log(s);
```

The `undefined` in the above code indicates to return the resulting string in a format appropriate for the user's current language.

You can also specify a time zone when using [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) directly, which offers further capabilities such as getting each part separately with [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts).  For example:

```js
function getDateValues(date, timeZone) {
    const fmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { timeZone });
    const parts = fmt.formatToParts(date);

    let year, month, day;
    for (const part of parts) {
        switch (part.type) {
            case 'year':
                year = parseInt(part.value);
                break;
            case 'month':
                // note, months are 1-12 (not 0-11 like Date.getMonth)
                month = parseInt(part.value);
                break;
            case 'day':
                day = parseInt(part.value);
                break;
        }
    }

    return {year, month, day};
}

const now = new Date();
const values = getDateValues(new Date(), 'America/New_York');
console.log(values);
```

Note in this case, I specify English (`'en')` for the language, so that I can be assured the resulting strings contain parsable numbers.